# UINavigationController pushViewController lifecycle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a two ViewControllers A and B, in between I use UINavigationController's `pushViewController` function to navigate, for example when press button on A, it navigates to B by executing:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[BViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
```

When press button on B, it navigates to A by the same way.

I think every time I navigate in this way, I am creating a new instance of a view controller without deleting the old one. For example, if I navigate `A -> B -> A`, there will be two A controllers.

How can I better manage the memory in this case? Is there a recommended pattern to reuse generated view controllers (like singleton view controller?), or how should I properly release the view controller which is not in use?

Thank you

Comment: If B not released, maybe B have been circularly retained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, if you navigate between A and B, the workflow should be like:

Push,      A -> B,

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[BViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
```

Then Pop,  A <- B,

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

So that A is the same instance.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, in this case, after navigate back to A, is B instance released?

Comment: Yes.  B is released.  (You can even go to C from B with just A and C on the stack.  To do that you will pop B with animated==NO, then push C with animated==YES).